# Powershell function with no errors and no results

Tags: powershell

I would like to scan the batch of my local networks to find all standalone Wi-Fi AP. I'm going to archive this by checking the TCP/80 port. I have 89 networks in the text file.
My script is below. The script seems to run but I get no output either to the screen or to any file.
I would be very appreciative if someone could tell me what's wrong.

#PSVersion                      7.1.3
#-----------------------------------------

```
function Test-Port() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [Alias('tp')]
        [string[]]$network,
        [int]$port = 80
    )
    #Begin { Write-Verbose "Scanning network $network"}
    Process {
        1..254 | ForEach-Object -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10 {
            $ip = "$network.$_"
            If ($(Test-netConnection –ComputerName $ip -Port $port -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).TcpTestSucceeded ) {
                Write-Output "$ip port $port open" | Out-File "C:\tmp\$network.txt"
            }   
        }
    }
}

[string[]]$lans = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\lans.txt"
   
#$lans | Test-Port
Test-Port -network $lans
```

### ======
Even this doesn't work with -Parallel. It just doesn't see the $n.

```
[string[]]$networks = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\lans.txt"
[string[]]$a = 1..50
foreach ($n in $networks) {  
     ForEach-Object -InputObject ($a) -parallel {
         write-output $n
     }  }
```

---

And it works fine without -parallel

Comment: Do you know the function works? Is the variable `$lans` populated?

Comment: so ... if you strip out all the function stuff and just run the core code ... where does it stop outputting info?

Comment: @Alex_P Yes, $lans populated. i.e.
...
192.168.3
10.2.18
10.2.30
10.2.11
10.2.18
10.222.176
...etc

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it works fine out of function. And moreover, it works fine inside the function if I remove -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10

Comment: Outside the function. And without -Parallel.
Just this part:
-----
[string[]]$networks = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\lans.txt"

foreach ($net in $networks) {  
    1..254 | ForEach-Object  {
         $ip = "$net.$_"
         If ($(Test-netConnection –ComputerName $ip -Port 80 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).TcpTestSucceeded ) {
             Write-Output "$ip port $port open"  | Out-File "C:\tmp\$net.txt" -Append
         } 
     }  
     }
-----
Works fine. But it's very slow because of the quantity of IP addresses.
If I add -Parallel I see
WARNING: Name resolution of .88 failed

Comment: And the same for each "IP"

Comment: @TheauthoroftheComment - i see that you found the problem - you left off the needed "pass the value into the parallel scriptblock". glad that you found it ... and the fix! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

`$network` is a string *array*, you need to loop over it :)

```
function Test-Port() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [Alias('tp')]
        [string[]]$network,
        [int]$port = 80
    )
    #Begin { Write-Verbose "Scanning network $network"}
    Process {
        foreach($net in $network){
            1..254 | ForEach-Object -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10 {
                $ip = "$net.$_"
                If ($(Test-netConnection –ComputerName $ip -Port $port -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).TcpTestSucceeded ) {
                    Write-Output "$ip port $port open" | Out-File "C:\tmp\$network.txt"
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course :). You're right. I fixed this part. And change Out-File to  Out-File "C:\tmp\$net.txt" -Append.
BUT. It doesn't work anyway. 
Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see the mistake....

Comment: So, it works fine after I removed -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10  part.
What a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!
The trick is $using

### $ip = "$($using:net).$_"

```
function Test-Port() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [Alias('tp')]
        [string[]]$networks
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($net in $networks) {  
            1..254 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
                $ip = "$($using:net).$_"
                If ($((Test-NetConnection –ComputerName $ip -Port 80 -InformationLevel Quiet).TcpTestSucceeded)) {
                Write-Output "$ip port 80 is open"  | Out-File "C:\tmp\$($using:net).txt" -Append
                } 
            }  
        }
    }
}


[string[]]$networks = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\lans.txt"

Test-Port -networks $networks
```

---

It works.
Thanks to all for your help, guys!

Comment: Please mark Mathias post as the answer if he answered your request.